# how can i display image JPanel in another JPanel

Tags: java, swing

Here is what I am trying to do is one JPanel Class with JLabel and JField, and one JPanel Class with option of inserting images in it, but when I run the StdPoto Class separately it works fine open JFileChooser and show image on the JPanel, but when I run it in Testing class, Testing Class only show the components of StudentData class and StdPhoto is missing

Photo panel which didn't appear in Testing Class

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.io.File;

public class StdPhoto extends JPanel {

    JLabel imageLabel = null;
    Icon stImage = null;
    JFileChooser fileChooser = null;
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = null;
    File fChoose = null;

    public StdPhoto() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    fChoose = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                String sName = fChoose.getAbsolutePath();
                stImage = new ImageIcon(sName);
                imageLabel = new JLabel("", stImage, JLabel.CENTER);                
                add(imageLabel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
                setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 100));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Class which works fine in Testing class

```
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;

import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;

public class StudentData extends JPanel {

    /**
     * Create the panel.
     */


    public StudentData() {

        GridBagLayout gbLayout = new GridBagLayout();
        setLayout(gbLayout);
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();

        gbc.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 10;
        gbc.weightx = 0.2;
        JLabel stNameLabel = new JLabel("Student Name", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        stNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        gbLayout.setConstraints(stNameLabel, gbc);
        add(stNameLabel);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        JTextField stNameField = new JTextField(15);
        stNameField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        gbLayout.setConstraints(stNameField, gbc);
        add(stNameField);

        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 5;
        JLabel fNameLabel = new JLabel("Father Name", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        fNameLabel.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        gbLayout.setConstraints(fNameLabel, gbc);
        add(fNameLabel);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 1;
        gbc.gridheight = 1;
        gbc.gridwidth = 1;
        JTextField fNameField = new JTextField(15);
        fNameField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        gbLayout.setConstraints(fNameField, gbc);
        add(fNameField);


        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        JLabel pAddress = new JLabel("Permenant Address", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        pAddress.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        gbLayout.setConstraints(pAddress, gbc);
        add(pAddress);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 3;
        JTextField pAddressField = new JTextField(15);
        pAddressField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        gbLayout.setConstraints(pAddressField, gbc);
        add(pAddressField);


        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 4;
        JLabel contactNo = new JLabel("Mobile No.", SwingConstants.LEFT);
        contactNo.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        gbLayout.setConstraints(contactNo, gbc);
        add(contactNo);

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        JTextField contactNoField = new JTextField(15);
        contactNoField.setFont(new Font("Calibri", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        gbLayout.setConstraints(contactNoField, gbc);
        add(contactNoField);

    }

}
```

Testing Class where i put the two frame together

```
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Testing extends JFrame {

    public Testing() {
        setSize(400, 200);
        JPanel jp1 = new JPanel();
        GridBagLayout gbl = new GridBagLayout();
        GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
        jp1.setLayout(gbl);
        gbc.gridx = 0;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbl.setConstraints(new StudentData(), gbc);
        jp1.add(new StudentData());

        gbc.gridx = 1;
        gbc.gridy = 0;
        gbl.setConstraints(new StdPhoto(), gbc);
        jp1.add(new StdPhoto());
        add(jp1);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Testing();
    }

}
```

Comment: Can you please add some punctuation to your first paragraph so it's easier to understand what you want to say? It's currently hard to figure out which words belong to which sentence and thus, what they actually mean.

Comment: The biggest problem is the default size of your `StdPhoto` component is `0x0`

Comment: did you mean to add setPreferredSize(), setMaximumSize() and setMinimumSize() to StdPhoto, if this, its not working

Comment: *"did you mean.."* I doubt it. But a tip: Add @MadProgrammer (or whoever, the `@` is important) to *notify* the person of a new comment.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I am not replying this to anyone i just do it so I post it here

Comment: *"I am not replying this to anyone.."* The first three words of your first comment were *"did you mean.."*. In those three words, who is 'you' referring to?

Comment: @AndrewThompson  mean my answer is not a reply to anyone I am here to just learn

Answer (score 0):

the corrected code for 'StdPhoto' and it works fine in this I initialize the 'JLabel' first and then do other work

```
   import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.BevelBorder;
import javax.swing.border.Border;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;
import java.io.File;

public class StdPhoto extends JPanel {

    JLabel imageLabel = null;
    Icon stImage = null;
    JFileChooser fileChooser = null;
    FileNameExtensionFilter filter = null;
    File fChoose = null;
    Border border = null;
    TitledBorder title = null;

    public StdPhoto() {
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        imageLabel = new JLabel();
        border = BorderFactory.createLoweredBevelBorder();
        title = BorderFactory.createTitledBorder(border, "Picutre");
        title.setTitlePosition(TitledBorder.ABOVE_TOP);
        imageLabel.setBorder(title);
        imageLabel.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 150));
        imageLabel.setMinimumSize(getPreferredSize());
        imageLabel.setMaximumSize(getPreferredSize());

        add(imageLabel);
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        filter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("Image Files", "jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg");
        fileChooser.setFileFilter(filter);
        imageLabel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
                int result = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(null);
                if(result == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
                    fChoose = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
                String sName = fChoose.getAbsolutePath();
                stImage = new ImageIcon(sName);
                imageLabel.setIcon(stImage);
            }
        });
    }
}
```